# Install to "Program Files (x86)" on 64bit host

Tags: 64-bit, nsis

I am trying to use "x64.nsh" to set default installation directory to `PROGRAMFILES64` if on 64bit host. The installer script looks similar to this:

```
!include x64.nsh
# set to default here, override in .onInit if on 64bit
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\AppName"

function .onInit
    ${If} ${RunningX64}
        SetRegView 64
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES64\AppName"
    ${EndIf}
functionEnd
```

but it stubbornly installs to `c:\Program Files\AppName`.

I've seen a few examples ([this one](http://bojan-komazec.blogspot.cz/2011/10/nsis-installer-for-64-bit-windows.html) in particular) but none of them seems to work for me. Is there any full example?

Is it related to the fact that nsis creates a 32-bit installer (`PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386`), even when packing 64bit code on 64bit OS?

**EDIT**: I actually don't mind having a 64-bit-only installer, since there is (and likely won't be) a 32bit build. But I can't seem to get `Program Files (x86)` from the `$PROGRAMFILES64` variable.

Comment: try swapping out PROGRAMFILES64 to its 32 bit counterpart? Maybe this might work? I cant really understand the override technique but give it a shot

Comment: I dont see the issue. `$PROGRAMFILES64\AppName` points to `c:\Program Files\AppName` on a 64-bit system which it does correctly.

Comment: @leppie: I see in my windows installation 64bit programs installed in `Program Files (x86)`. Since my app is native 64bit, I want to install there as well. Should I uses something else than `$PROGRAMFILES64` to achieve that?

Comment: @eudoxos: No, 32-bit programs go in `Program Files (x86)` on a 64-bit system

Comment: @leppie: ok, I double-checked [at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Files), you're right! I was confused by many 64bit (`PE32+`) binaries installed in `Program Files (x86)`, such as some from ATI, and I assumed ATI got ti right :|. Can you put your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @eudoxos: Just answer it yourself ;p

Comment: @leppie: ok, I just checked you don't care about a few points of extra reputation ;-) Appreciate your effort, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by @leppie, it is correct to install 64bit binaries into `c:\Program Files` (not `c:
Program Files (x86)` as I believed based installation of some other 64bit software. A 64bit-only installer can use `$PROGRAMFILES64` directly.